# on joomla site, Pages show, then disapear, only in ie6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, joomla

strange bug, only in IE6.
http://www.pagovernorsconferenceforwomen.org/

when you click on any of the navigation items, you get a page to load, for a second, then it disapears, and leaves only a blank browser window.

Has anyone else dealt with an issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

Could be [the Peek-a-boo bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html).

I notice that `div#columns` has a left float and is immediately followed by a clearing div.

Try "giving it layout", as [described here](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).